# Docker image fails to create netlink handle

Tags: docker, netlink

Can anyone help me make sense of the below error and others like it? I've Googled around, but nothing makes sense for my context. I download my Docker Image, but the container refuses to start. The namespace referenced is not always 26, but could be anything from 20-29. I am launching my Docker container onto an EC2 instance and pulling the image from AWS ECR. The error is persistent no matter if I re-launch the instance completely or restart docker.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: 
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused 
"process_linux.go:334: running prestart hook 0 caused \"error running 
hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: time=\\\"2017-05-
11T21:00:18Z\\\" level=fatal msg=\\\"failed to create a netlink handle: 
failed to set into network namespace 26 while creating netlink socket: 
invalid argument\\\" \\n\"".
```

Comment: Someone has reported that as a bug recently: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33656

Comment: That someone is me! :)

Comment: You confused me because the different user names! Ha ha nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update from my Github issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33656

It seems like the DeepSecurity agent (ds_agent) running on a container with Docker can cause this issue invariably. A number of other users reported this problem, causing me to investigate. I previously installed ds_agent on these boxes, before replacing it with other software as a business decision, which is when the problem went away. If you are having this problem, might be worthwhile to check if you are running the ds_agent process, or other similar services that could be causing a conflict using 'htop' as the user in the issue above did.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running it with the `--privileged` option?

If it still doesn't run, try adding `--security-opts seccomp=unconfined` and either `--security-opts apparmor=unconfined` or `--security-opts selinux=unconfined` depending whether you're running Ubuntu or a distribution with SELinux enabled, respectively.

If it works, try substituting the `--privileged option` with --cap-add=NET_ADMIN` instead, as running containers in privileged mode is discouraged for security reasons.